C wrapper to iterate a C++ map
I am building a module in C++ which will also be used by some C code.
The C++ module makes use of std::map to manage some objects.
I would like to write a C wrapper to return some info about the objects using an iterator pattern. (the solution should also work if the objects are in a std::vector)
In C++, I can just iterate over the objects like this:
#include <iostream>
#include <map>
#include <memory>

template <typename T>
class EntityManager
{
public:
    typedef std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<T>> EntityMap;
    typedef typename EntityMap::const_iterator Iterator;
    void registerEntity(int id, std::unique_ptr<T> &&entity)
    {
        entityMap.insert(std::make_pair( id,std::move(entity)));
    }
    Iterator begin() const { return entityMap.begin(); }
    Iterator end() const { return entityMap.end(); }
private:
    // all the objects live in here
    EntityMap entityMap;
};

typedef EntityManager<std::string> MyManager;
auto myManager = MyManager();

int main()
{
    typedef EntityManager<std::string> MyManager;
    auto myManager = MyManager();
    myManager.registerEntity(1, std::make_unique<std::string>("I'm number one!"));
    myManager.registerEntity(2, std::make_unique<std::string>("I'm number two!"));

    auto it = myManager.begin();
    auto itEnd = myManager.end();
    for (; it != itEnd; ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->first << ": " << *(it->second) << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}

Prints:
1: I'm number one!
2: I'm number two!

But my C code obviously doesn't know anything about STL containers and iterators.  I want to provide a C-style iterator function that achieves the same effect.
I guess the iterator type could be an opaque pointer to something dynamically allocated by the C++ code.  Or it could be an opaque struct created on the stack by the calling C code.
    // it is a pointer to some opaque dynamic mem
    my_iterator_t it = my_iterator_create();
    for (; !my_iterator_done(it); my_iterator_next(it))
    {
        const my_info_type *res = my_iterator_get_info(it);
        // do something with info about the thing...
    }
    my_iterator_release(it); // need to free memory

    // OR:

    // it is an opaque struct on the stack
    my_iterator_t it;
    my_iterator_create(&it);
    const my_type *res;
    while (res = my_iterator_next(&it) != NULL)
    {
        // do something with res...
    }
    // no need to release iterator because it lives on the stack

EDIT for clarity: The C++ would wrap a global object of a specific type.  Here's what I think the wrapper functions should look like:
extern "C" my_iterator_t my_iterator_create()
{
    // what goes here??
    // Wrap myManager.begin() and pass it to the C code?
}
extern "C" const my_type * my_iterator_next(my_iterator_t it)
{
    // what goes here??
    // dereference the iterator
    // increment the iterator
}


Not an easy journey. But for starters you can rely on plain pointer arithmetics in case of POD types for vector iterators (i.e. they behave like T* for std::vector<T>).

@πάνταῥεῖ vector iterators might be pointers but they might not be, whether T is POD probably isn't relevant? You could just ignore vector iterators and get a pointer from data, won't work with a map though

I may have made my C++ example too generic.  The C wrapper just needs to work for a global object of a specific type.  I'll try to update the question to clarify.

@AlanBirtles yeah,  accessing data from the c code Was the immediate thought after

Consider two functions.  One gets the first, one gets next.  Remember to catch all exceptions so they don't propagate out to the c functions.

Why wrap the iterator instead of make a for each?

Iterating over a C++ vector in C is much easier than iterating over a map (because C knows how to iterate over an array). I suggest replacing "vector" with "map" in your title, and replacing "std::vector and/or std::map" with "std::map (and/or a std::vector)". That keeps the focus on the map and makes the vector an afterthought that should be accounted for.

The generic approach would be to put C++ objects on heap and return a pointer that C code would pass to a disposal function when done. For contiguous containers like vector, a pair of index and  pointer to container  would minimize the overhead, while keeping the option to check for validity. Unfortunately std iterators are not guaranteed to be trivial, so memcpy is not an option.

@JeffGarrett I'm open to other approaches. Would you please elaborate? In general, I just need my C code to get info about a lot of C++ objects in manageable chunks.

@Red.Wave Yes, I'm definitely interested in the "generic approach", but I've been unable to find an example. Would you please point me to a reference or provide an answer which fills out my wrapper functions?

I would usually expect a for_each style from a C API... void for_each_my_type(void (*fn)(void* userdata, const my_type* elem), void* userdata), something like that would be more typical I think

I'd suggest you consider the simplest approach, which is to provide index-based access. That could be implemented for any container rather easily, using std::advance(). It would also be something every C programmer is familiar with. Downside of course is that getting from an index to the actual position is an O(n) operation for some containers, but if n is small and this is not used in performance-critical code, that should be good enough.

@UlrichEckhardt thanks, this makes sense. While not ideal, I think it should work for now. It is meant to run on a microcontroller (ESP32) so I'm trying to keep it efficient and low memory.

I think I figured out what I am trying to do after stumbling on this old blog post: http://www.olivierlanglois.net/idioms_for_using_cpp_in_c_programs.html
It compiles and runs. But I have not analyzed it for memory leaks.  Suggestions for improvement are welcomed.
The header is shared with the C code, so must not contain any C++ stuff.  The C++ iterator is cast to a void* and then wrapped in a struct. (I'm not sure the struct is necessary here.)
// Header.h
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C"
{
#endif

    typedef struct
    {
        int id;
        char string[64];
    } my_info_t;

    /* C style iterator */
    typedef struct
    {
        void *m; /* Must be typeless as you cannot include a C++ template class declaration in C modules  */
    } my_iterator_t;
    my_iterator_t *my_iterator_create();
    void my_iterator_release(my_iterator_t *);
    int my_iterator_next(my_iterator_t *, my_info_t *);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

The C++ implementation has a global object so the C wrapper can access it at all times.  (I simplified my example to just use a bare std::map instead of a custom class for clarity.)
typedef std::map<int, std::unique_ptr<std::string>> MyMap;
typedef typename MyMap::const_iterator MyIterator;
auto myMap = MyMap(); // global object

C wrapper functions
/*
 * For every C wrapped method that need to use the map, 
 * use this inline function to retrieve the map from the void*.
 */
inline MyIterator *getIteratorObj(my_iterator_t *s)
{
    return static_cast<MyIterator *>(s->m);
}
// You must wrap your C functions entry points to be sure that
// C++ exceptions do not cross into C modules.
// But exceptions have already been disabled in my case (ESP-IDF)
my_iterator_t *my_iterator_create()
{
    // try {
    my_iterator_t *res = new my_iterator_t;
    res->m = new MyIterator(myMap.begin());
    return res;
    // }
    // catch (...) { }
    // return NULL;
}

void my_iterator_release(my_iterator_t *s)
{
    delete getIteratorObj(s);
    delete s;
}

int my_iterator_next(my_iterator_t *s, my_info_t *info_out)
{
    auto it = getIteratorObj(s);
    if (*it == myMap.end())
    {
        return 0; // no more entities
    }
    info_out->id = (*it)->first; // dereference the iterator
    auto string = *((*it)->second); 
    auto strLen = string.length();
    if (strLen > sizeof(info_out->string) - 1)
    {
        strLen = sizeof(info_out->string) - 1; // leave room for null terminator
    }
    string.copy(info_out->string, strLen);
    info_out->string[strLen] = 0; // null terminate C string
    (*it)++;                     // increment the iterator
    return 1;
}


A main function showing how to use the C wrapper
int main()
{
    // Setup
    myMap.insert(std::make_pair(
        1, // ID for map
        std::make_unique<std::string>("I'm number one!")));
    myMap.insert(std::make_pair(
        2, // ID for map
        std::make_unique<std::string>("I'm number two!")));

    // This is how to iterate it from C++
    auto it = myMap.begin();
    auto itEnd = myMap.end();
    for (; it != itEnd; ++it)
    {
        std::cout << it->first << ": " << *(it->second) << "\n";
    }

    // This is how to use it from C
    my_iterator_t *cit_to_release = my_iterator_create();
    my_info_t my_info;
    while (my_iterator_next(cit_to_release, &my_info))
    {
        printf("%d: %s\n", my_info.id, my_info.string);
    }
    my_iterator_release(cit_to_release);

    return 0;
}

Here's a link to try the full code at cpp.sh

my_iterator_create need not return a pointer. my_iterator_t being a struct makes it abstract and adds an extra level of safety against operator manipulations. Using void pointer hides the details of implementation. You'd better use char* my_info_t::string; and info_out->string=string.c_str(); . This is faster, more generic, less error-prone. Leave the string copy and manipulations to consuming C code. You can optionally add the size_t my_info_t::lenght; to optimize the consumer C code using sized versions of string functions.

@Red.Wave thanks for the tips!  Are you recommending that my_iterator_create() returns the struct by value? i.e. my_iterator_t my_iterator_create();  Or are you suggesting that it accepts a pointer to my_iterator_t and it returns an error code? I.e. int my_iterator_create(my_iterator_t *s);  I guess those are functionally the same, as the struct now lives on the caller's stack so there's one fewer new and delete required.

To remove one unnecessary indirection along with is mem management costs, the intuitive syntax would be my_iterator_t my_iterator_create(my_arg_t); to have the result as return value. If the return type cannot handle a null state, then just add a bool or enum member to my_iterator_t, so you can check for null or error; of-course you'll provide an accessor function bool is_valid(my_iterator_t const) to avoid member access. The destructor would be void my_iterator_release(my_iterator_t*); who sets the value to null for safety. You can also implement reference-counting.
